# php parse geojson multilevel string

Tags: php, json, parsing, geojson

I am struggling to parse a geojson string returned from mapbox to get latitude and longitude co-ordinates, but struggling to get the data needed.

My current code is:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$myPostcodeLat = $json->features[0]->center[0];
$myPostcodeLong = $json->features[0]->center[1];
```

[image]

I know the url is correct and is returning the data correctly, it is just the parsing of the data that is returned that isnt working for me.

I have tried a few of the other SO responses to parsing JSON data, but with no luck so far in getting the two required fields.

Comment: `centre` vs `center`. Enable error_reporting, if you haven't already.

Comment: Oops, thats an error in my post. Edited now!

Comment: Use `var_dump`, or paste your JSON into http://array.include-once.org/ to get a PHP-style representation.

Comment: That's a really useful site, and has helped me track down the error. If you make this comment into an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Great link @mario!!! That site is a lifesaver. Take the good man's advice and make your comment into an answer!

Comment: @mikey_w Thanks. This happens to be a project of mine, and specifically made for Stackoverflow questions no less.  However I only rarely post it as comment even, because it otherwise looks too much like attention-addiction IMO. (However I'll go find a duplicate to cross-hyperlink a nice reference..)